# Which code is correct when using TypeOrm Lazy Type?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

The official TypeOrm document says to use Promise when using Lazy Type. But I didn't use that method because I had the Lazy option. What is the difference between the two methods?

```
@Entity('COMPANY')
export class Company extends TimeStamped {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
    companyId: number;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
    companyName: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Employee, (employee) => employee.company, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        lazy: true
    })
    employee: Employee[];
}
```

```
@Entity('COMPANY')
export class Company extends TimeStamped {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
    companyId: number;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
    companyName: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Employee, (employee) => employee.company, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    })
    employee: Promise<Employee[]>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [Typeorm relation options code](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/decorator/options/RelationOptions.ts#L56):

```js
export interface RelationOptions {
    ...

    /**
     * Set this relation to be lazy. Note: lazy relations are promises.
     * When you call them they return a promise which resolves relation 
     * result then. If your property's type is Promise then this relation
     * is set to lazy automatically.
     */
    lazy?: boolean;

    ...
}
```

In your first example, when you want the value of `employee` you will have to write something like:

```js
const employees = await company.employee;
```

But if a developer checks the code later, he might be confused as why there is an `await` on a property of a class that is not a promise.

In your seconds example, you will write the same code as above. But now, any developer will know that the property is a promise therefore they have to `await` (This will also help the ESLint).

So ideally, you should use your second example or the following one which I believe is more intuitive to the developer:

```js
@OneToMany(() => Employee, (employee) => employee.company, {
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  lazy: true
})
employee: Promise<Employee[]>;
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply as always. Eventually, it works the same, but the good readability is the Promise expression, right?

Comment: Correct, both your examples work perfectly as long as the developer knows where to put `await`. It is just the readability of the code might be harder in the 1st example than the 2nd

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. I wish you good luck all the time.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help 

Comment: Setting values on these can get a bit messy. Might be good to add examples to your answer.